# object of type 'closure' is not subsettable, that doesn't make sense in this situation

Tags: r

I read a few questions that you have already answered however, it doesn't seem to make sense in my situation. you stated in someone else question that they were writing their line as if they were using a function as a dataframe.   I get the following error message for the line below:

"Error in data[train, ] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"

> booastmodel<- ada(default ~ .,data=data[train,],iter=50,bag.frac=0.5,control=rpart.control(maxdepth=30,
>   + cp=0.01,minsplit=20,xval=10))

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: does object data exist. Otherwise R will use the function `data()`

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. But at a quick glance, is train a vector of indices? You'll get this error if not.

Comment: "train"  is the variable.   I am using ada() for the first time so maybe I don't understand what it is asking for.  Can you clarify it for me?

Comment: Page 2:  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ada/ada.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The error message means that `data` is a *function*. And indeed that’s how `data` is predefined in R. You probably misspelled your variable name (i.e. your variable isn’t called `data`).

Comment: my variable is train.  so are you tell me of "data=data[train,]"  I need to remove "data?  and if so, which one?

Comment: @user7268950 Just call the function as `ada(default ~ ., data = train, …rest of arguments…)`, unless you want to subset `train` — and in that case, subset *`train`*, not `data`.